# MySQL Add Row on SELECT Query

Tags: mysql

My database structure: (table name is `company_info`)

```
 |comp_id | comp_name          | comp_nature
 | 001    | Citigroup, Inc.    | Bank
 | 002    | Harvard University | Academe
 | 003    | Western Union      | Courier
 | 004    | C.I.A.             | Government Agency
```

I wanted to create a query that would count `comp_nature`. But if `comp_nature` IS NOT "Bank" or "Academe", I wanted it to be categorized as "Other", so the result of the query should look something like this..

```
 | comp_nature       | count |
 | Bank              | 1     |
 | Academe           | 1     |
 | Other             | 2     |
```

I was able to use the `COUNT` keyword, but I couldn't seem to get how to create a "row" (Other) in a `SELECT` statement. (Or is this even possible in just one `SELECT` statement?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be something like this:

```
select comp_nature, count(*) as cnt from
(
select 
 case when comp_nature in('bank','acadme') then comp_nature 
 else 'Other' end as comp_nature 
from company_info
) as X
group by comp_nature
order by <whatever makes sense>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select 
    case 
        when comp_nature not in ('Academe', 'Bank') then 'other' 
        else comp_nature end as col, 
    count(*) from t 
group by col
```